# Passing argument to SerialDataReceivedEventHandler via another function

Tags: c#

How do I get this to work please....
I am trying to pass the event handler to a function which handles the call back.
.............main routine............

```
    ConnectPorts(DataReceivedHandlerFREQ_FL );
```

......................................

.............function being called to setup event handler..........

```
    static void ConnectPort(???? DataReceivedHandlerFREQ_FL)
    {
            SerialPort FLfreqPort = new SerialPort(MyGlobals.ComPortFLFQ, 153600);
            FLfreqPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandlerFREQ_FL);
    }
```

...............................................................

.......................... the handler is defined here........................

```
    private static void DataReceivedHandlerRFID_FL(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            DataReceivedHandlerRFID(sender,  e, 0);
     }
```

Comment: Then what is the problem you are getting when you pass this.

Comment: I can't get it to compile.... I dont know what I should use in place of the ??????